# Input returning the void when programmed not to

Tags: java

```
public static void gender(){
    System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = name.nextLine();
    if(!s.equals("boy") || !s.equals("girl") || !s.equals("Boy") || !s.equals("Girl")){
        System.out.println("Please pick an option");
        gender();
    }
    if(s.equals("boy")){
        System.out.println("You are a boy.");
    }
    if(s.equals("Boy")){
        System.out.print("You are a boy.");
    }
    if(s.equals("girl")){
        System.out.println("You are a girl.");
    } 
    if(s.equals("Girl")){
        System.out.print("You are a girl.");
    }
}
```

I'm programming the method to reset itself when the desired input isn't inputted. However, it still returns the method when the correct one is entered.

Comment: Have a look at the _.equalsIgnoreCase()_ method, it might help in a few places here.

Comment: Read your code out loud "if s is not 'boy' OR s is not 'girl'..."

Comment: You want `&&`, not or `||`. If the input is boy, then it isn't girl, so you are always entering that if statement

Comment: Putting the 'wrong' input i.e. not a boy or a girl recursively calls gender() when I run it. Can I make a design suggestion and say consider using a loop for the input instead of recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Read the case out loud...

You want it to be NOT (boy or girl), instead of what you have NOT boy or NOT girl.

Obviously, if a girl, it isn't boy, vice versa, and same for all other input.

Either replace `||` with `&&`, or keep the or statements, move the negation to the front of the statement so you actually have "NOT (boy or girl)"... Notice the parenthesis.

And you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` to reduce the code.

Also, try a `while (true)` loop instead of recursion (calling the method within itself), and just `break` on a valid input.

If you want to keep the recursion, then the method needs to not be void. Preferably, you should `return s` in either case. For recursion,  `return gender()`.

Comment: Yeah, the recursion in the OP's code is going to cause great problem when returning as `s` is not being assigned to from `gender`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void gender(){
    System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = name.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    if(s.equals("boy")){
        System.out.println("You are a boy.");
    }

    else if(s.equals("girl")){
        System.out.println("You are a girl.");
    } 

    else {
        gender();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. If u enter boy or girl (case insensitive) it will print the line stating your input otherwise will call the method again until u enter correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can control exit when input is correct (you dont have to call it again), I recommend also to use `equalsIgnoreCase`. it's less code.

Take a look at this:

### Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        String s;
        boolean isCorrect = false;
        
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Are you a boy or a girl?");
            Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
            s = name.nextLine();
            if(!(s.equalsIgnoreCase ( "boy" ) || s.equalsIgnoreCase ( "girl" )))
            {
                System.out.println("Please pick a correct option");            

            }
            else
            {
                isCorrect = true;
                System.out.println ( "Nice, you are a " + s.toLowerCase ( ) );
            }
        }
        while ( !isCorrect );
        
   }
```

### Example output:

> Are you a boy or a girl?
>
> s
>
> Please pick a correct option
>
> Are you a boy or a girl?
>
> c
>
> Please pick a correct option
>
> Are you a boy or a girl?
>
> bOy
>
> Nice, you are a boy

### Documentation:

[Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flowsummary.html)